# Protecting android application

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to ensure that my application (apk) uploaded in play store can not be downloaded by any one on PC and uploaded to other stores like Amazon. It is a free app.

Please let me know if any API/configurtion helps above?

Comment: there really isnt a way, anyone with a rooted phone can just pull the APK from their phone and do what they want with it. you would have to do something in your code to authenticate the package if you are that concerned

Answer (score 1):

If it's free I don't really understand the concern.

But you could upload an APK with the same signature and package name to the app stores you don't want it in and just supply them with a non functional apk or even a non related description. You would essentially be just reserving the package namespace.

Another alternative is you could at runtime check where the package was installed from via:
[getInstallerPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) This sort of gets around the issue. Like if you detect the apk is not installed by adb or by the google vending app (play store) then you just exit the process or initiate some sort of messaging to the user, or send the package to your server and you can deal with the appstore in question directly. This is not 100% either only because someone could decompile your app and remove this check.

Basically there is no real way to toally prevent it, but you can make it rather difficult for someone to do.